# Space characters after images in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I stumbled across some bizarre behavior in Firefox 12. Consider the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<img src="resources/csv.png">
<img src="resources/globe.png">
<img src="resources/clock.png">
<img src="resources/key.png">
<img src="resources/delete.png">
```

When this renders, I notice there's a small space between the first and second images. If I do a "text selection" around all of the images, I see there's a sneaky little whitespace character between them:

[image: wtfspace]

I can think of no reason for this, but my intention is to make all of my buttons links instead, so I tried that too to see if it had any effect. Here's the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<a><img src="resources/csv.png"></a>
<a><img src="resources/globe.png"></a>
<a><img src="resources/clock.png"></a>
<a><img src="resources/key.png"></a>
<a><img src="resources/delete.png"></a>
```

Once again, here's the rendered output, which has been selected. Notice now there's a space after each image:

[image]

Can anyone think of a logical explanation for this quirk? Is it a problem in my HTML, or perhaps a bug in Firefox? Can anyone think of a workaround, perhaps with CSS? My first instinct is to play with the margins, but I need to be IE7 compatible, which I think does not work with negative margins if I recall correctly. Thanks much.

EDIT: Oops. I forgot that a carriage return turns into a space character in HTML. Still, many thanks to the answerers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white space is the carriage return. remove that and you'll be golden!

```
<img src="one.jpg"><img src="two.jpg">
```

or

```
<a href="#"><img src="one.jpg"></a><a 
href="#"><img src="two.jpg"></a>
```

is usually how I mark it in my html when I need to get rid of that whitespace.

Comment: There are line breaks following each `<img>` tag. Can you explain why only one shows up between the first and second, and nowhere else? That's what I believe the question is asking.

Comment: no, but I know if you remove the whitespace between the tags it works. I have run into that many times.

Comment: @BoltClock White space between tags is all truncated to a single space in html.

Comment: yes, that is why a carriage return leaves Tom with an annoying single space between images.

Comment: @mayhewr: Is that in any way related to whitespace between self-closing `<img>` tags versus `<a></a>` tags where whitespace *doesn't* collapse?

Comment: @BoltClock Perhaps what is confusing is when non-inline tags are placed inside of <a> tags, which forces space into them.  They are more obviously collapsing when only inline elements are inside them.  Whitespace is all truncated to 1 space in HTML, but styling (CSS) can create more space. Play with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etGcL/) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Putting them all on one line will fix it.

```
<img src="resources/csv.png"/><img src="resources/globe.png"/><img src="resources/clock.png"/><img src="resources/key.png"/><img src="resources/delete.png"/>
```

But that can be cumbersome.  If you want to preserve some readability, you might do something like...

```
   <img src="resources/csv.png"/><!--
--><img src="resources/globe.png"/><!--
--><img src="resources/clock.png"/><!--
--><img src="resources/key.png"/><!--
--><img src="resources/delete.png"/>
```